# Multiple resonances in a circuit

Tags: capacitor, inductor, ltspice, impedance, resonance

So I have been struggling a little to understand why when we measure the impedance of the inductance over a large frequency range multiple resonances occur. To do so, I model a 2 turns inductor in LTspice as seen here [image: here],

where R in series with L refer to the resistive and inductive parts of the inductor, R//C the capacitive coupling between the two.

As presented in this picture below, where I plot the impedance of the system (1/I(V1)) [image]:
the first resonance is the parallel resonance of L1 and C2, with the value of the impedance at this frequency is equal to R1+L1/(R1.C2). The third resonance is that of L2//C1, with again the value of the impedance at this resonance frequency $f_{res3}$ is equal to R2+L2/(R2.C1). However, when it comes to the second resonance, the series one between L2 and R2, I am having a very hard time determining the value of the impedance a $f_{res2}$. Any ideas please?

PS: The analytical expression is so complex...

Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like the anti-resonance (series resonance) of L2 and C2. However, your graph axis is unknown so it's impossible to really know. I don't know what any of this has got to do with modelling an inductor though (especially so given that the capacitance across L1 is 100 times the capacitance across L2).

Comment: @Andyaka the y axis of the graph is the impedance of the system 1/I(V1)

Comment: @Andyaka it is indeed the series resonance, but what about the value of the impedance at this frequency (what are the influencing parameters), because I cannot seem to figure it out...

Comment: @Andyaka The capacitor across L2 is the capacitor to the ground (permittivity of air < permittivity of dielectric) that is why.

Comment: @Andyaka I mentioned above that I did a mini model to see what parameters influence what...

Comment: I have doubts the model is well made (considering the values), but if you want to model an inuctor you need to model it at scale, because the capacitances and inductances are distributed, you can't just introduce discrete instances of parasitics wherever you think they might reside. There's a reason why making a brute, lumped LC model will not match a transmission line, or a cable, because the disctributed values act "in volume" (not sure about my choice of words, I hope you get the message). Also, why did you add 10 V DC to the source, and not a current source with `AC 1` for direct results?

Comment: Using a lumped element model at 1 GHz seems a little questionable to me.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Thank you for your comment! I used not so that of random values (sort of tried to respect the order of magnitude) to study the impact their values have on the response of the system (I would sometimes multiply C2 by 10 to see what it affects), and my problem resides in the value of the impedance at the series resonance. Also when you said distributed, isn't that exactly what I did?  Each turn has a resistive and inductive behavior and both are coupled through a capacitor//resistor given the dielectric energy & losses. Your choice of words was well understood, thanks!

Comment: @Hilmar Just to study the sensibility. Also it is only two turns inductor, resonances will occur at very high frequencies. I did want to create a very big complex circuit to get lost in my sensibility study. Thank you for your remark by the way :)

Comment: @Wallflower Did not you forget coupling of inductors ?

Comment: @Wallflower  What kind of "inductor" would you simulate ?

Comment: Please use engineering notations for your component values.

Comment: @Antonio51 The turns are indeed mutually coupled. I wanted to go with the basic coupling before including the mutuals and  studying their influence on the response of the system ;) Concerning the second question, it is a 2 turns inductor, just two turns one next to another with no magnetic material.

Comment: @winny engineering notations?

Comment: 10 pF = engineering notation. 1*10^-8 or 1e-8 = scientific notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read first $7.2.6 of "RF MicroElectronics" Razavi.

There is a number of topologies ...

Here is an example.

[image]

Here an example of "tree" inductance ...
If "coupling" is higher, for the same "configuration", resonance frequencies go higher ...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. However concerning the book you mentioned are you sure it's the 7.2.6?

Comment: It is only an example ... fig 7.14 and 7.15